# Matrix $A^T A$ as sum of outer products

Tags: matrices, statistics, outer-product

I have recently read in a script about statistical methods in a chapter about linear regression that:

> Given an $n \times k$-matrix $A$, we have
>
> $$A^T A = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^T a_i$$
>
> where $a_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of $A$.

Unfortunately, the author doesn't give a proof of that and I can't figure out one myself. Maybe someone can help me.

source: [script](http://www.luchsinger-mathematics.ch/sm6.pdf) on page 10

Comment: More generally: If $A$ is an $n \times k$-matrix, and if $B$ is an $m \times n$-matrix, then $BA = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i a_i$, where $a_i$ means the $i$-th row of $A$, and where $b_i$ means the $i$-th column of $B$.

Comment: Related later [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4147099)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hint:

$$A = 
\left[\begin{array}{ll} a_1\\0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\0 \end{array}\right] + 
\left[\begin{array}{ll} 0\\a_2\\ 0\\ \vdots\\0 \end{array}\right] + \dots +
\left[\begin{array}{ll} 0\\0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\a_n \end{array}\right]
$$

$$
A^TA = A^T\left[\begin{array}{ll} a_1\\0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\0 \end{array}\right] + 
A^T\left[\begin{array}{ll} 0\\a_2\\ 0\\ \vdots\\0 \end{array}\right] + \dots +
A^T\left[\begin{array}{ll} 0\\0\\ 0\\ \vdots\\a_n \end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Sometimes it's that easy...you helped me a lot. Thank you.