# $PQ= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i q_i^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof

For matrices $P \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $Q \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$, let $p_i$ be the $i^{th}$ column of $P$, and $q_i^T$ the $i^{th}$ line of $Q$. We want to show that $$PQ= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i q_i^T$$

I saw a proof using the fact that $\sum_k p_kq_k^T=\sum_k \sum_i \sum_j p_{ik}q_{kj}M_{ij}$ with $M_{ij}$ a matrix full of zeros everywhere except $(M_{ij})_{ij}=1$.

Is there a proof that does not use triple sums ?

Comment: it's worth pointing out that the formula is obviously true (i.e. no computation needed) when $Q$ is invertible, because $\mathbf q_i^TQ^{-1} = \mathbf e_i^T$ and $PQQ^{-1}=P=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf p_i\mathbf e_i^T$.  (A similar argument can be run on invertible P.)

Comment: Note that $A=B$ **iff** $Ax=Bx$ for all $x$. Note that $PQx = P \begin{bmatrix} q_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ q_n^T x \end{bmatrix} = \sum_k (q_k^T x) p_k = \sum_k p_k q_k^T x$ and so $PQ=\sum_k p_k q_k^T $.

Comment: By $(M_{ij})_{ij}=1$ you presumably mean $(M_{ij})_{kl}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, maybe the special case of your statement is easier to visualize if we, instead of $x,$ just consider the vectors of the canonical basis for $\Bbb R^n:$ $$\begin{aligned}PQe_j&=\sum_{i=1}^nq_{ij}Pe_i,j=1,\ldots,d\\\Rightarrow PQ&=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^nq_{i1}Pe_i&\ldots&\sum_{i=1}^nq_{id}Pe_i\end{bmatrix}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\begin{bmatrix}q_{i1}Pe_i&\ldots&q_{id}Pe_i\end{bmatrix}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^nPe_i\begin{bmatrix}q_{i1}&\ldots&q_{id}\end{bmatrix}\\&=\sum_{i=1}^nPe_ie_i^TQ\\&=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^ne_ie_i^T\right)Q\\&=PQ\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}$Let $\e_k$ denote the canonical vector basis for
${\mathbb R}^{n}$, then the indexed vectors can be written in terms of
the underlying matrices as
$$\eqalign{p_k = P\e_k \quad\qquad q_k^T = e_k^TQ}$$
Therefore the sum in question can be expanded as
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{k=1}^n p_kq_k^T
&= \sum_{k=1}^n P\e_k\e_k^TQ \\
&=  P\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\e_k\e_k^T\right)Q  \\
&=  P\,I_n\,Q  \\
&=  PQ  \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Check that the $i,j$ entry of the left-hand side is the $i,j$ entry of the right-hand side.

If you think about how the matrix multiplication $PQ$ works, you will note that the $i,j$ entry of $PQ$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n p_{ik} q_{kj}$.

For the right-hand side $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k q_k^\top$, note that $p_{ik} q_{kj}$ is the $i,j$ entry of $p_k q_k^\top$.